# Cross-checking each item in a list with every other item in the same list in a parallel fashion

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a list of several thousand items. Each item has an attribute called "address range". I have a function that verifies the correctness of the items in the list by making sure that none of their address ranges overlap with the address ranges of any other items in the list (each item has precisely one address range). If ***N*** is the number of entries in the list, I essentially have to run (***N***-1)*(***N***/2) address range overlap checks. In other words, if the number of items in the list doubles, the number of overlap checks quadruples.

Months ago, such a list would only have a few thousand items, and the whole operation would finish relatively quickly, but over time the number of items has grown, and now it takes several minutes to run all the cross-checks.

I've been trying to parallelize the cross-checks, but I have yet to think of a feasible approach. My problem is that if I want to distribute the cross-checks to perform over say 8 threads (to fully exploit the CPUs on the computer), I would have to split the possible cross-check combinations into 8 independent chunks.

To use an example, say we have 5 items in our list: ( A, B, C, D, E ). Using the formula (***N***-1)*(***N***/2), we can see that this requires (5-1)*(5/2)=10 cross-checks:

```
A vs B
A vs C
A vs D
A vs E
B vs C
B vs D
B vs E
C vs D
C vs E
D vs E
```

The only way I can think of to distribute the cross-check combinations across a given number of threads is to first create a list all cross-check combination pairs and then split that list into evenly sized chunks. That would work in principle, but even for just 20,000 items that list would already contain (20,000-1)*(20,000/2)=199,990,000 entries!!

So my question is, is there some super-sophisticated algorithm that would allow me to pass the entire list of items to each thread and then have each individual thread figure out by itself which cross-checks it should run so that no 2 threads would repeat the same cross-checks?

I'm programming this in Perl, but really the problem is independent from any particular programming language.

EDIT: Hmmm, I'm now wondering if I've been going about this the wrong way altogether. If I could sort the items by their address ranges, I could just walk through the sorted list and check if any item overlaps with its successor item. I'll try that and see if that speeds things up.

UPDATE: Oh my God, this actually works!!! :D Using a pre-sorted list, the entire operation takes 0.7 seconds for 11,700 items, where my previous naive implementation would take 2 to 3 minutes!

UPDATE AFTER usr's comment: As usr has noted, just checking each item against its immediate successor is not enough. As I'm walking through the sorted list, I'm dragging along an additional (initially empty) list in which I keep track of all items involved in the current overlap. Each time an item is found to overlap with its successor item, the successor item is added to the list (if the list was previously empty, the current item itself is also added). As soon as an item does NOT overlap with its successor item, I locally cross-check all items in my additional list against each other and then clear that list (the same operation is performed if there are still any items in my additional list after I've finished walking the list of all items).

My unit tests seem to confirm that this algorithm works; at least with all the examples I've fed it so far.

Comment: Checking just the predecessor is not enough. There might be more matching items further back. Those could have a bigger range start value but the end of the range might still overlap. Right?

Comment: @usr: Yes, I didn't tell you the whole truth. It actually took a little more than what I initially said. I will update my post to provide the full solution.

Comment: I admit I do not follow the description 100% because my coffee is not ready yet. I think your algorithm would mistakenly clear the list with these ranges: [0, 120], [10,100], [110,111]. The ranges 0 and 2 overlap but because 1 and 2 do not overlap you clear the list.; But I have one question: Can each "item" have more than one range?

Comment: Excellent point. I extended my unit tests, and it turns out you're correct. I've now adjusted the algorithm to not just check if a successor items overlaps with its predecessor but also with any of the items stored in my secondary overlap list.

I will probably refactor this a little, as my suspicion is that I'm now actually running a few unnecessary checks.

Comment: Can each "item" have more than one range?

Comment: No, each item is guaranteed to have precisely one range. Sorry, I should have mentioned that to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could create N threads where N = number of cores on the computer. Each of these threads is identical and consumes items from the queue until there are no more items. Each item is the comparison pair that the thread should work on. Since an item can only be consumed once, you will get no duplicate work.

On the producer side, simply send every valid combination to the queue (just the pairs of items); the threads are what does the work on each item. Thus there is no need to spit the items into chunks.

It would be great if each thread could be pinned to a core, but whatever OS you're running on will most likely do a good enough job at scheduling that you won't need to worry about that.

Comment: As far as I understand that would require me to do exactly what I said I was trying to avoid, i.e. create a list of all possible item combinations first. Or did I misread your answer?

Comment: You don't have to create a list. You have a loop that computes the next item and puts it on the queue. That part is serial, but that's the part that doesn't need to be parallelized (assuming the work-side is really the slow part).